# Cumulative groupby with condition on datetime pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I need to calculate cumulative sums for different columns in a pandas dataframe based on a column playerId and a datetime column. My dataframe looks like this:

```
      eventId  playerId  goal  shot  header  dateutc
0     0        100       0     1     0       2020-11-08 17:00:00
1     1        100       0     0     1       2020-11-08 17:00:00
2     2        100       1     1     0       2020-11-08 17:00:00
3     3        200       0     1     0       2020-11-08 17:00:00      
4     4        100       1     0     1       2020-11-15 17:00:00
5     5        100       1     1     0       2020-11-15 17:00:00
6     6        200       1     1     0       2020-11-15 17:00:00
```

So now I need to calculate cumulative sums for each player for the current date and all previous dates. So my final dateframe will look like this:

```
      playerId  dateutc              goal  shot  header
0     100       2020-11-08 17:00:00  1     2     1
1     200       2020-11-08 17:00:00  0     1     0
2     100       2020-11-15 17:00:00  3     3     2
3     200       2020-11-15 17:00:00  1     2     0
```

Hopefully someone can help me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First remove `eventId` for avoid `sum` if numeric, aggregate `sum` and then `cumsum`:

```
df1 = (df.drop('eventId',axis=1)
         .groupby(['playerId','dateutc'], sort=False)
         .sum()
         .groupby(level=0, sort=False)
         .cumsum()
         .reset_index())
print (df1)
   playerId              dateutc  goal  shot  header
0       100  2020-11-08 17:00:00     1     2       1
1       200  2020-11-08 17:00:00     0     1       0
2       100  2020-11-15 17:00:00     3     3       2
3       200  2020-11-15 17:00:00     1     2       0
```

If need specify columns for processing:

```
df1 = (df.groupby(['playerId','dateutc'], sort=False)[['goal', 'shot', 'header']]
         .sum()
         .groupby(level=0, sort=False)
         .cumsum()
         .reset_index())
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
out = df.groupby(['playerId', 'dateutc'], sort=False)[['goal', 'shot', 'header']].sum()
out = out.groupby(level='playerId').cumsum().reset_index()
```

Output:

```
>>> out
   playerId              dateutc  goal  shot  header
0       100  2020-11-08 17:00:00     1     2       1
1       200  2020-11-08 17:00:00     0     1       0
2       100  2020-11-15 17:00:00     3     3       2
3       200  2020-11-15 17:00:00     1     2       0
```